# Referencing 'onclick' event for If statement - IE automation

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, onclick

Apologies if this is a bit confusing. However, I am a little out of my depth here. I have a macro which is automating IE. At one point my macro navigates to a URL that is used to download a report. The URL is almost always the same. However, one digit within the link can sometimes change. The digit in the link that changes can only be `1` or `2`. The `onclick` event of the button to get the report gives an indication which report will be generated. As a result, I need my macro to have an `IF` statement to read the `onclick` and if the `onclick` has `1`, then it will navigate to the link with a `1` or if it is a `2`, it will navigate to the link with a `2`. I have provided the `onclick` details below:

````
Link with 'ReporttypeID=1'

<input name="btnContinue" class="primary" id="btnContinue" onclick="javascript:pop('Splash.aspx?SplashID=3&amp;../Reports/ReportView.aspx&amp;ReporttypeID=1&amp;lang=EN&amp;ruletypeid=5&amp;ruleid=0'); return false;" type="submit" value="Continue">```

Link with 'ReporttypeID=2'

<input name="btnContinue" class="primary" id="btnContinue" onclick="javascript:pop('Splash.aspx?SplashID=3&amp;../Reports/ReportView.aspx&amp;ReporttypeID=2&amp;lang=EN&amp;ruletypeid=5&amp;ruleid=0'); return false;" type="submit" value="Continue">```
````

My code is below, how do I call/reference the onclick id?

```
Sub login()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim url As String
    url = UserForm.Path2.Value

    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie 'Open IE
        .navigate url
        ieBusy ie
        .Visible = False

        ie.navigate "https://mylink.com/ReporttypeID=1" 'Currently navigate to this set link
    'Need IF statement to say if onclick = 1 then go to above link, else if it = 2 then go to the below link
        'ie.navigate "https://mylink.com/ReporttypeID=2"

        ieBusy ie

    End With 'End IE actions

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These answers are based on there being one or the other always present.

Extract the onclick attribute and test whether it contains the string `"ReporttypeID=1"`

```
If Instr(ie.document.getElementById("btnContinue").getAttribute("onclick"),"ReporttypeID=1")> 0 Then
    'report 1
Else
  'report 2
End If
```

An alternative is to use a css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) with contains operator to check nodeList length

```
If ie.document.querySelectorAll("[onclick*='ReporttypeID=1']").Length > 0 Then
    'report 1
Else
  'report 2
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not get the first solution to work as I kept getting debug errors for objects not defined, not sure if potentially there is something missing from my code however the second solution worked perfectly. Thankyou! IE automation is a bit out of my depth and I only recently learned how to manipulate pages from finding ID's, are you able to elaborate on what the css attribute does and how it works?

Comment: There is a really good explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors  We apply the css selector via querySelector or querySelectorAll method of HTMLDocument (ie.document) and this returns either the first match as a node, or all matches as a nodeList (respectively). The nodeList has a .Length property which tells you how many nodes were retrieved for the css selector.